# Why doesn't the OpenMP atomic directive support assignment?

Tags: parallel-processing, atomic, openmp

The atomic directive in openmp supports stuff like

```
x += expr
x *= expr
```

where expr is an expression of scalar type that does not reference x. I get that, but I don't get why you can't do:

```
#pragma omp atomic
x = y;
```

Is this somehow more taxing cpu instruction-wise? Seems to me that both the legal and illegal statement loads the value of x and some other scalar value, changes the register value of x and writes it back. If anyone could explain to me how these instructions are (I assume) fundamentally different I would be very grateful.

Comment: This is now possible in OpenMP 3.1  -->  `atomic update`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because the suggested atomic assignment does not protect against anything.

Remember that an atomic instruction can be thought of as a critical section that could be (but does not have to be) efficiently implemented by the compiler by using magic hardware. Think about two threads reaching `x = y` with shared `x` and private `y`. After all the threads finish, `x` is equal to the last thread to execute "wins" and sets `x` to its `y`. Wrap the assignment in a critical section and nothing changes, the last thread still "wins". Now, if the threads do something else with `x` afterwards the slowest thread may not have caught up and even if it has the compiler could legitimately end up using choosing to some cached value for `x` (i.e. the thread's local `y`). To avoid this, you would need a barrier (so the winning thread has won) and its implied flush (so the local cache has been invalidated):

```
x = y;
#pragma omp barrier
\\ do something with shared x...
```

but I cannot think of a good reason to do this. Why do all the work to find y on many threads if most of them will be (non-deterministically) thrown away?

Comment: Atomic assignment *is* useful. If the type of the value of X and Y is "large" in any sense, doing an atomic copy ensures that the resulting value X doesn't contain an inconsistent picture of any value Y that might be copied. You also need, of course, "atomic read" (you suggested a barrier) to make sure that fetching a component of X doesn't get you a part of one value, as your race situtation above describes. What I would have said is that the overhead for protecting individual copies is in general pretty high, and this might not be that helpful from a performance point of view.

Comment: -1: This answer is incorrect. The [OpenMP 3.0 standard](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/spec30.pdf#page=22) does not guarantee atomicity when reading from or writing to shared variables: “The minimum size at which memory accesses by multiple threads without synchronization, either to the same variable or to different variables that are part of the same variable (as array or structure elements), are atomic with respect to each other, is 
implementation defined.” OpenMP 3.1 introduced atomic read/write specifically to address this limitation.